# Polyfill CSS Transition with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, modernizr

For starters, I don't know `js`. What I do know, I've pick pocketed from other people's work. I know that's lame so I'm trying to learn. I am trying to polyfill my nav that use css transitions with `Modernizr`. I've got the `<script>` in the `HTML` that calls for `Modernizr`. What I don't know is what `js` to use to call the correct `load function` - I think. I've looked all over the internet for tutorials, but they all assume that I already know `js` so they are no help.

This is [my site](http://dev.newfrequency.com/index.html) in progress. What I'm working on is the navigation. It works correctly in `Firefox`. I'm trying to make it work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's no need to apologise for learning from others. This is how we all learn.

Modernizr is great for helping you deal with older browsers. But the important thing to know about Modernizr is that it doesn't actually do any polyfills itself; it simply tells you whether a polyfill is needed for any given feature. You still need to provide that polyfill code.

In your case, you're referencing a file called `polyfillfortransition.js`, but this doesn't seem to exist on your site. This is why nothing is working: you're detecting that the polyfill  needed, but you're not actually polyfilling it.

So you need a polyfill script for it. I don't actually know of one that will suit, and a quick search didn't turn one up, but hopefully this will help point you in the right direction.

Comment: So I downloaded a script that I found called `jquery.transitions.js`. I put it in the `js` folder and corrected the link in the `<script>` and it still doesn't appear to work. Am I missing something. This is where I got the `js` `https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js` if that helps.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but I think it does the opposite of what you want -- ie it makes jQuery's animations use CSS transitions internally. You want a script that takes the CSS transition code and turns it into jQuery anims.